# intelliJ IDEA: is showing only 10 libraries to download

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

When I go to Settings > Languages and frameworks > Javascript > Libraries > Download, just 10 libraries are shown:

[image]

I know I can download manually the libraries and add it from the disk, but there is a way I can configure the ide or the project to show more libraries available to download?

Comment: I have the same problem. :(